# Windows Service speed

Tags: c#

I have a issue regarding two timers in Windows Service 
The second TimerLimit is never executed. 
I have set up two timers because i need one to check to parse some email and i need it to do constantly while second one just if something happens after having reading emails. I have an impression they are in conflict.
Is it possible because the first timer is too fast ? 
any suggestion to solve this issue ? 
Thank you in advance

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        stop = false;
        ParseEmail.DeleteFiles();
        timer = new Timer(200);
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(ExecuteService);
        timer.Enabled = true;
        timerLimit = new Timer(20000);
        timerLimit.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(ExecuteServiceLimit);
        timerLimit.Enabled = true;
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        stop = true;
    }

    private void ExecuteService(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (stop)
        {
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            if (ParseEmail.isNotUse)
            {
                ParseEmail.isNotUse = false;
                ParseEmail.ParseValues();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            ParseEmail.isNotUse = true;
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", exp.ToString());
        }
    }
    private void ExecuteServiceLimit(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (stop)
        {
            return;
        }
        try
        {
                ParseEmail.CheckLimitOrders();
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", exp.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You'll need to improve your error logging.  Console.WriteLine() cannot work in a service.  Your code may be dying on an exception and you'll never know.  Use EventLog, for example.  And stop the service so you don't fill up the log with thousands of errors.

Answer (score 0):

It's really strange what you write.
Try to see the CPU load from task manager, and if it's to high you have to increase the first timer period. Also check how much time ParseEmail.ParseValues() takes to you.

I'll see that you reset

```
ParseEmail.isNotUse = true;
```

only when you have an exception, is it correct?
So you run once this function!

Comment: CPU is normal is not so high. Yes only when i have exception.

Answer (score 0):

First, your intervals are awfully small. If that's a [`System.Timers.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx), it's in *milliseconds*. 200ms is 5 times per second.  Do you really need to process these tasks that quickly?

Second, what's going on in timer 1? Because it's interval is so small, it fires first. If it's taking forever to complete, it may be hogging all your CPU cycles, preventing timer 2 from firing. (Not likely, but possible.)

Also, it's possible that your first timer is firing before you've even completed setting up the second timer.

Now, I believe you're using a `System.Timers.Timer`, based on the constructor. However, I will say this: Consider a [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) to process the tasks on separate threads of execution. That way, one doesn't block the other. But ONLY do that after you've determined reasonable firing times, and that the data involved is thread-safe, and that you won't allocate to many threads at once.

Comment: Yes i am using System.Timers.timer. 200 milliseconds has been set because I receive emails every moment and i need to parse them constantly. These email contains trading signal and ParseEmail.ParseValue() takes info from them and send orders to the market. Second timer is because if something happens during execution, there should be a check, this check is executed by second timer. Now second timer is never executed. I don't understand much about BackgroundWorker could you please so kind to post an example. thank you so much for your help